# Find and parse url in dom-element value using RegExp and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Here is part of my html code:

```
<span id="ctl08"><object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" height="50" width="150">
              <param name="movie" value="/Flash/Dg_Inverse.swf?secEncCode=9e2ec595c926065318629a6dfea6b2ed">
              <param name="quality" value="high">
```

I need to find such element in my code:

```
<param name="movie" value="/Flash/Dg_Inverse.swf?secEncCode=9e2ec595c926065318629a6dfea6b2ed">
```

As well I'd like to know how to get only `9e2ec595c926065318629a6dfea6b2ed` as a variable?

**So how to find element's value using jQuery and RegExp?**
I did not try anything so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var value = $("param[name='movie']").val();//get attribyte value
if(value && (value = value.match(/secEncCode=(\w+)/))){//reg exp
  value = value[1];//get first pocket
  console.log(value);//res
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xbQxw/

**update by comment**

If you want change secEncCode value:

```
var param = $("param[name='movie']"),//get obj
    value=param.val(),//get attribyte value
    key; 
 if(value && (key = value.match(/secEncCode=(\w+)/))){//reg exp
     key = key[1];//get first pocket
     param.val(value.replace(key, "YOUR NEW KEY"));//replace key
 }
```

Comment: hm, how to be if i have /Flash/Dg_Inverse.swf?secEncCode=   how to set / as not second /

Comment: hm( didn't work.... maybe becouse  i have /Flash/Dg_Inverse.swf?secEncCode as value?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to extract the end part out the value

first select the element

```
$('param[name=movie]')
```

then you can use split or regex or whatever you want.  Here's an example with split

```
var yourvariable = $('param[name=movie]').val().split('=')[1];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XbBbC/

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery [attribute-ends-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/):

```
var strmatch = "secEncCode=9e2ec595c926065318629a6dfea6b2ed";
$element = $('[value$='+strmatch+']'); // a jQuery object, not a DOM element
```

Comment: one error... 9e2ec595c926065318629a6dfea6b2ed is not fixed, but dynamic.... then i need to use var strmatch = "secEndCode="; ?

Comment: You can pass whatever you want in as a string. I used a variable `strmatch` to keep it simple that way.